# If input field is completed remove class jquery

Tags: jquery, input, removeclass

trying to remove a validation class from dropdown depending on if a field before has been completed.

here is the code

```
 $('#NatCode').on('keyup', function () {
     // check if input has something in it
     if ($(this).val() != "") {

         $('#optone, #carNum').addClass('required');
     } else {
         $('#optone, #carNum').removeClass('required');
     }
 });
```

and here is part of the html

```
<div>
          <label for="NatCode" class="label">Eurotax NatCode </label>
          <input name="00N11000000KAoq" type="text" id="NatCode" maxlength="80" size="20" title="Please type your natcode."/>
</div>



<label for="model" class="label model">Marque</label>
<select id="optone" name="00N20000003bgum" size="1" onchange="setOptions(document.signup.optone.options[ document.signup.optone.selectedIndex].value);" title="Please choose a make" class="required">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="ABARTH">ABARTH</option>
    <option value="ALFA ROMEO">ALFA ROMEO</option>
    <option value="ASTON MARTIN">ASTON MARTIN</option>
    <option value="AUDI">AUDI</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="" class="label model">model</label>
    <select id="carNum" name="00N20000003bog1" size="1" maxlength="80" class="required">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Model of car</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm new to jquery, am I completely missing something here?

Comment: the selector `NatCode` is wrong if it is the id then try `#NatCode`

Comment: sorry missed that out on the post '#NatCode' still doesnt work

Comment: where is the `NatCode` element

Comment: where is `$('NatCode')` in your HTML?

Comment: is the `NatCode` dynamically created

Comment: check your script console, you might have an error somewhere else. It'd be useful if you post you whole markup (i.e. including the NatCode element you're trying to hook to)

Comment: its a input field, just added it in

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/n7Nzv/

Comment: do you have any errors in your script console?

Comment: Jamiec that works, i swopped them round thou as i need it to be validated at start and unvalidated in inputed. This works but i see you took off the onchange= in the #optone select. Is this what stopping it.

Comment: try moving the script after the markup in your document so the NatCode element is loaded when the hook is made, or change it to $(document).on( "keyup", "#NatCode", function(){....});

Comment: i took that off because you didnt give us that function, so I had no idea what it does/did. If that causes a javascript error, then it very well could be the problem

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/W5q99/1/

Comment: is your logic right here? What your code does is, if the text input field is filled, it adds the classes 'required' to the dropdowns. Is that what you mean? Or is it supposed to be the other way around?